# IIS/ASP.NET custom error pages on OOM/SO

Tags: asp.net, iis, out-of-memory, stack-overflow, custom-error-pages

We have some logic for displaying custom error pages in our ASP.NET application through overriding Page.OnError. Now, when an error occurs within that error handling routine I can redirect somewhere else using the  in web.config.

This works for most errors. Yet, I cannot find how to display a custom error page (or anything at all!) when getting e.g. a StackOverflowException. Obviously I cannot do any more processing insode ASP in such a case as practically anything will result in some allocation on the stack. The same is probably true for OutOfMemory, though I have not found any sensible way to test this. Is there any possibility I could still display something (possibly static) to the user, e.g. directly from IIS instead from ASP?

Comment: If you're catching the exception sufficiently far out of the code that fails, there's no reason why you shouldn't be able to run cleanup code - the problematic stuff will already be out of scope.

Comment: Well, basically the question is: How do I handle an unforseen exception _inside_ the error handler? I can do that using customErrors in web.config, but not for OOM and SO.

Comment: Can you catch the error in Global.asax?

Comment: The error handling is currently situated in an override of OnError in our root page template. Since not even the customErrors approach works in the case of a SO I doubt that I will be able to do any processing in Global.asax. That's why I was asking for an approach using IIS in the original post.